# How do I fix my scanner input that is null?

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, pointers, null

Hi I am new at java programming and ran into a problem on my latest project. I am making a score generator for bowling and finished the code, except when I went to test it, it said

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Bowling_Score.main(Bowling_Score.java:34)"

I tried everything to fix it, and looked through tons of websites, but no solutions solved my problem. It's probably something really easy to fix, but I can't seem to find the answer. The line that has the problem is the second line here.

```
    System.out.println("Frame 1, Throw 1");
    Frame1Throw1 = sc.nextInt();
```

This is the only way I know how to use a scanner with variables, so if there is a better way please tell me. It also may be a problem because the variable Frame1Throw1 is the first variable on the list.

The variable is correct, and my scanner's name is sc

Please be specific with your answer, because as I said, I am new at java, and am just learning the basics now. This is my first big project.

Thank You!

P.S. I use eclipse to code I don't know if that matters or not

*** I got one answer, and it was helpful, but It didn't work. Here is some more of the beginning of the code which may be helpful in answering.

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Bowling_Score {

     private static Scanner sc;
public static void main(String[] args) {
//All Variables
    int Frame1Throw1 = 0;
    int Frame1Throw2 = 0;
    int Frame2Throw1 = 0;
    int Frame2Throw2 = 0;
    int Frame3Throw1 = 0;
    int Frame3Throw2 = 0;
    int Frame4Throw1 = 0;
     //Then I have one variable for each throw of the game, and one for the final total score.
        //Directions
    System.out.println("To put in your score, put the number of pins you  knocked down in the throw specified. If you get a strike, enter a 10 in the first throw of the frame and a 0 in the second throw of the frame. If you get a spare, Ener a 0 in the first throw of the frame and 10 in the second throw of the frame.");

    //Frame 1
    System.out.println("Frame 1, Throw 1");
    Frame1Throw1 = sc.nextInt();
    if (Frame1Throw1 == 10){
        Frame1Throw1 = Frame1Throw1 + Frame2Throw1 + Frame2Throw2;
        Frame1Throw2 = 0; }
```

Comment: You might have to provide some more code in order for us to find the error

Comment: What is Frame1Throw1 and where did you initialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` means that the object you are referencing hasn't been initialised. So in this case I imagine that your `sc` hasn't been created previously in your code.

Look for something like

```
Scanner sc;
```

and change it to

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Otherwise it could be a scope problem (you created the object somewhere that can't be seen by that method) you'll need to provide more code if the first solution doesn't work.

Comment: thanks but it didnt work. I added some more code that may be helpful

Comment: From looking at your code, I can see you haven't intialised your scanner. Change the line `private static Scanner sc;` to `private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`, that should fix your problem.

Comment: Or try creating the entire object within your `main()` function. i.e. using the line I provided in my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot i did it right in the past but I guess when I went through to check I missed that.